# Powershell Jobs not returning what I expect

Tags: multithreading, powershell, parallel-processing, jobs, start-job

I have this PowerShell script that reads lines of integers from a file and creates a new job with $CHUNK_SIZE amount of lines to get the sum of all the prime numbers until the end of the file. The $MAX_THREADS is the amount of jobs hat can be running at the same time, I'm testing with 1, but will change to 2, 4, and 8 later. I wait for all the jobs to complete and then receive all the subtotals from the jobs to get the actual sum of all primes in the file. My problem is that the accumulated total at the end should be 2844292, but I keep getting 2766271. I have checked my prime function and whats being read from the file and being sent to the job - but they do not seem to be the problem. When I look at my output, I notice that I receive the same value twice in a row for the last two jobs..i'm not sure why that's happening. 
These photos show my output:

1.[Get-Job Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkdaZ.png)

2.[What I get back from Receive-Job and my total increasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEupw.png)

Any help as to why my total is off would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
Set-StrictMode -Version latest

$CHUNK_SIZE = 1024
$MAX_THREADS = 1


$scriptBlock = {
    param($chunkArr)

    function isPrime([int]$data){
        if($data -lt 2){return $FALSE}
        if($data -eq 2){return $TRUE}
        if($data % 2 -eq 0){return $FALSE}
        for($i=3;$i*$i-le$data;$i+=2){
            if($data % $i -eq 0){return $FALSE}
        }
        return $TRUE
    } 

    $total = 0
    foreach($line in $chunkArr){
        $data = [int]$line
        if(isPrime $data){
            $total += $data
        }
    }
    $total 
}

$eof = $FALSE
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader("$PWD/ass2-20000.txt")
$chunkArr = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
while(!$eof){
    $chunkArr.Clear()
    for($i=0;$i -lt $CHUNK_SIZE;$i++){
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if($line -eq $NULL){
            $eof = $TRUE
            break
        }
        $chunkArr.add($line) | Out-Null
    }
    While(@(Get-Job -state running).count -ge $MAX_THREADS){
        Start-Sleep -Seconds .2
    }
    Start-Job -ArgumentList (,$chunkArr) -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
}

While(@(Get-Job -state running).count -ge 1){
    Start-Sleep -Seconds .2
}
Get-Job
$total = 0

foreach($job in Get-Job){
    $tmp = Receive-job $job
    Write-Output ("Recieved: " + $tmp)
    $total += $tmp
    Write-Output ("Total: " + $total)
    Remove-Job $job
}

$reader.Close()
$total
```

EDIT: this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0ISi.png) shows what the jobs should be returning, the last line showing the correct total..it seems my first job is never being received and my last one is being received twice

EDIT: Compare [What I should be getting from each Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0ISi.png) to [What I actually get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEupw.png)

Comment: Yes, when running it without jobs the result is 2844292. This confirms that my prime function works, as well as pulling the data from the file. I calculated the sum of the primes in the file as well with an online calculator, so i'm sure that 2844292 is correct.

Comment: I see, the first chunk never gets returned, and the last one's value gets returned twice...could the problem be in my foreach, when I receive all the jobs?

Comment: If you look at my latest update, the photos will help. Basically the first job returns the value of the second chunk and so on, and the value i should be getting from the last job only, i get from the last two jobs. So it omits the value from the first chunk. But the values themselves (what was calculated and summed up in my scriptblock is correct)